# SOAP DSAPI.ASMX and API.ASMX Endpoints

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign API doc suggests to use DSAPI.ASMX endpoint where as I see that DSAPI internally call API.ASMX public methods which is an additional hop and couple of methods are not available in DS API.ASMX.

Is it possible to justify further on using DSAPI.ASMX other than API.ASMX?

By the way I don't see much information in documentation about API.ASMX, can you provide if any link for API.ASMX endpoint details just like DSAPI? or is Docusign mandating to using DSAPI?

Your advise is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dsapi.asmx (DocuSign API) is the current file. api.asmx is the prior version and is not recommended. I understand that dsapi makes use of the api file.

See [docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Using%20DocuSign%20WSDLs.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess then for dsapi we don't require Credential API for Authentication as we have to send the X-DocuSign-Authentication header instead of the WSE3 UsernameToken..

Comment: Right, that was a part of the dsapi changes. Thank you for developing with DocuSign.